# CSS: using div and background image, image not resizing to fit div size

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some social media icons which are sized at `71px` a piece. I want to shrink down the images to `50px` using CSS. I am using a `div` to do a `hover` effect and change it to a different image which is basically the same image, but tinted blue.

I can't figure out why my images are not resizing by setting the `background-size: cover` on them. They are being cut off like the image below.

Btw, I am using `Bootstrap`.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

        <div id="social_fb" class="social_icon"></div>
        <div id="social_twitter" class="social_icon"></div>
        <div id="social_gplus" class="social_icon"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 90px 0 0 0; 
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

#site_wrapper { 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

a { 
    text-decoration: none !important; 
}
a:hover { 
    color: #ed1c24; 
}

h1, h2, h3 { 
    margin: 0; 
    color: #888; 
}
h1 { 
    font-size: 30px; 
}
h2 { 
    font-size: 24px; 
}
h3 { 
    font-size: 20px; 
}

section > .container { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec; 
    padding-top: 80px; 
    padding-bottom: 80px; 
}

.valign_center { 
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

.nopadding { 
    padding: 0 !important; 
    margin: 0 !important;
}

#social_media .container { 
    padding-top: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 50px; 
}

#social_media h2 { 
    font-size: 28px; 
    color: #0095da; 
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
}

.social_icon { 
    display: block; 
    background-size:cover;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
}

#social_fb { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background: url("../images/social_fb.png"); 

}
#social_fb:hover { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-image: url("../images/social_fb_hover.png"); 
}

#social_twitter { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background: url("../images/social_twitter.png"); 
}
#social_twitter:hover { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-image: url("../images/social_twitter_hover.png"); 
}

#social_gplus { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background: url("../images/social_gplus.png"); 
}
#social_gplus:hover { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-image: url("../images/social_gplus_hover.png"); 
}
```

Comment: Did you tried with background-size: 100% 100% ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you are setting `background` in your styles for `#social_twitter`, `#social_fb`, etc. This is taking precedence over `background-size: cover`.

If you set the background property to `background-image` it should start working.

CSS

```
#social_fb { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-image: url("../images/social_fb.png"); 

}
#social_fb:hover { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-image: url("../images/social_fb_hover.png"); 
}

#social_twitter { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-image: url("../images/social_twitter.png"); 
}
#social_twitter:hover { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-image: url("../images/social_twitter_hover.png"); 
}

#social_gplus { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-image: url("../images/social_gplus.png"); 
}
#social_gplus:hover { 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-image: url("../images/social_gplus_hover.png"); 
}
```